# How to access non static timer or variables out of AppDelegate

Tags: ios, appdelegate

when my app enters the Background I want to change a value of variable of a specific class. My problem is: The class is not static so how can I reach this class?

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Register the class or the instance to the `AppDelegate`, then let the `AppDelegate` announce the event to your class/instance.

Comment: can you elaborate on your actual issue? i have the feeling that it lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AppDelegate, create a property of this Class and as soon as this class is loaded, set this AppDelegate property as self (the instance of the Class). Then you can access this property in the

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
}
```

method while your app goes to the background.